# How to jump out of the method inside Java 8 Iterator.forEachRemaining loop?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, iterator, return

The simplified code is below.  I expected that return inside the iteration will result in jumping out of the method. Instead the code executes the next iteration and then the print after iterations within the method

```
public static void callIter() {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("A");
    names.add("B");
    names.add("C");
    ListIterator<String> nameIterator = names.listIterator();
    nameIterator.forEachRemaining(name -> {
        if (name.equals("B")) {
            System.out.println("Found");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(name);
    });
    System.out.println("AfterIter");
}
```

Comment: In Java 9, intermediate operations were added for `takeWhile` and `skipUntil`, which have the effect of "slicing" a stream at the point where a predicate starts to be met / is no longer met.  You can then feed the resulting stream into `forEach()`.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: but with `takeWhile(…).forEach(…)` there is no clean way to detect whether a stop element has been encountered. `skipUntil` does not exist, which is no problem as it would only reverse the predicate of `dropWhile`.

Comment: @Holger Sorry, it's called `dropWhile()`.

Comment: If you want fine-grained control over when to stop, just use the regular iterator methods `hasNext()` and `next()`, and add your own additional termination logic.  (If you're working with a stream, you can ask it for an `Iterator` with the `iterator()` method.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `forEach` methods, whether `Iterable.forEach`, `Iterator.forEachRemaining` or `Stream.forEach` are intended to do what the name suggests, apply an action for *each* element, not just some.

Stopping the iteration is not forseen by this API, which can be recognized by looking at the functional signature of the `Consumer` interface, which is `(T) -> void`, not containg any possibility for the collection or iterator to notice a stop condition.

At this place, you should reconsider whether you are using the right tool for the job. Compare your approach with, e.g.

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
int ix = names.indexOf("B");
(ix<0? names: names.subList(0, ix)).forEach(System.out::println);
if(ix>=0) System.out.println("Found");
System.out.println("AfterIter");
```

Of course, if the printing of the elements was only for debugging purposes, the actual operation simplifies to

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
if(names.contains("B")) System.out.println("Found");
System.out.println("AfterIter");
```

If equality was only a placeholder for an arbitrary predicate, you may use

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
if(names.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.equals("B"))) System.out.println("Found");
System.out.println("AfterIter");
```

which can be adapted to arbitrary conditions.

This can be expanded to

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
Optional<String> match = names.stream()
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .filter(Predicate.isEqual("B"))
    .findFirst();

if(match.isPresent()) System.out.println("Found");
// or
match.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("Found "+s));

System.out.println("AfterIter");
```

showing, how you can debug the processing by printing the elements, an alternative way to express the equality predicate (still can be replaced by other predicates), and how to get the actual matching element for nontrivial predicates.

Generally, if you want to utilize the new APIs of Java 8, don’t try to write your logic in terms of `forEach`. Rather, try to avoid `forEach`, using more appropriate operations whenever possible.

Answer (score 8):

The `return` finishes execution of the code that is executed for each (remaining) element of the iterator. It does not stop execution of the iteration/`forEachRemaining`. This matches the behaviour you are describing.

The [Javadoc for `forEachRemaining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) states:

> Performs the given action for each remaining element until all
>   elements have been processed or the action throws an exception.
>   Actions are performed in the order of iteration, if that order is
>   specified. Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.

In other words, if you don't want to abuse exceptions for this, you should not use `forEachRemaining` if you intend to stop the iteration before processing the last element.

Answer (score 1):

*forEachRemaining* does not have option to break iteration. You can do search through stream operations, like this:

```
String name = names.stream().filter(name -> name.equals("B")).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, Iterator.forEachRemaining does not have an easy break since it is intended to run through `eachRemaining`. A way that I got around this issue was this style:

```
Iterator<Object> objects = ...;
    while (objects.hasNext() && exitCondition) {
      // Do what you would've inside of the for each
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my genius collegue advised me on this situation to throw a RuntimeException in the loop and catch it outside the forEachRemainin loop